# Pine sap removal from my patio pavers

Tags: cleaning

The white spots are caused by pine sap is there a way I can remove all of them in one shot instead of on my hands and knees

Comment: Have you tried a pressure washer?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the problem? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.